# PHP - La Zona Horario en Mexico no me la respeta

Tags: php, linux

Tengo problemas para mostrar la hora correcta en Mexico, hace unos dias cuando mostraba la hora me respetaba entre la hora central de Mexico y la hora frontera, ejemplo:

En el **Interior de la Republica**:

```
echo date("Y-m-d, h:i", time());
// 2023-04-06, 10:30
```

En la **frontera**:

```
echo date("Y-m-d, h:i", time());
// 2023-04-06, 11:30
```

Eso **era correcto** , pero ahora SIEMPRE me muestra la hora de frontera, ya no respeta ni detecta el cambio.

Mi configuracion actual en PHP es:

```
cat /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini | grep date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Mexico_City
```

Y en el codigo PHP de mi portal "index.php"

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");

echo '
<html>
... contenido web....
</html>
';
?>
```

Y aun asi, siempre me marca 1 hora adelantada, osease, horario de Frontera. Porque?

Comment: Al ya no usar horario de verano en 2023 las zonas horarias estan desfasadas, tomara algun tiempo hasta que los desarrolladores (en este caso de php) ajusten las zonas a las actuales. como parche temporal usa "America/Chihuahua"

Comment: La solucion fue hacer update al sistema y con eso quedo funcionando !

Answer (score 0):

Mexico tiene 4 zonas horarias.

| Mexican time zone | Standard | DST | U.S. equivalent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zona Sureste | UTC−05:00 | UTC−05:00 | Eastern Standard Time (EST) |
| Zona Centro | UTC−06:00 | UTC−05:00 | Central Time |
|  | UTC−06:00 | UTC−06:00 | Central Standard Time (CST) |
| Zona Pacífico | UTC−07:00 | UTC−06:00 | Mountain Time |
|  | UTC−07:00 | UTC−07:00 | Mountain Standard Time (MST) |
| Zona Noroeste | UTC−08:00 | UTC−07:00 | Pacific Time |

- Fuente: [Wikipedia - Time in Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Mexico)

Por lo que entendí, estas necesitando indicar la zona horaria `MST` o `Mexico/BajaNorte`

```php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
echo date("Y-m-d, h:i", time())."\n"; // 2023-04-06, 03:10

date_default_timezone_set("MST");
echo date("Y-m-d, h:i", time()); // 2023-04-06, 02:10

date_default_timezone_set("Mexico/BajaNorte");
echo date("Y-m-d, h:i", time())."\n"; // 2023-04-06, 02:10
```

- Referencia: [Manual PHP > Listado de zonas horarias admitidas > Otros](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.others.php)